# Prestashop 1.7 classic theme product page

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Prestashop 1.7 classic theme.

### how can i make the cart, quantity , price show different order on the product page? like quantity and size would be first and price would be last to show.

Answer (score 1):

You should sort respective html code to achieve this. This is in product.tpl of classic theme.